# Android app indexing works only with English search

Tags: android, firebase, android-app-indexing

I have implemented app indexing in my app according to the tutorials on the Firebase website. I just wanted only two features, nothing special.

- Open the app, when the associated link was clicked in the search.
- If the app is not installed, show the card of the app, what redirects to the play store.

The strange thing is, that the app install card is showing only, when the search language is set to English, and it isn't showing for any other language.

Do you have any idea what is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Did you get any answer for this issue?